# Reorganize table in SQL

Tags: sql

Here is the SQL query with the result table:

```
USE DataBase

SELECT * 
FROM table
```

[image]

I want to reorganize table that

1. Use element of `Category` as column;
2. The value of `Ccy` is from `Str/Num`, which depends on the `Value Type` (`s` means take value from `str`; `n` means take value from `Num`).

And here is the expected result:

[image]

I usually import table into Pandas. Not sure if it can be done directly in SQL?

Comment: You are likely going to want a `pivot`. Which DBMS is this?

Comment: YEs it can be done in SQLm but you need to answer: 1. What is the database? 2. Is the number of output columns variable? (i.e. can there be a D,E,F)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea for a `pivot` on this data is going to be something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
 SELECT ccy, category, CASE WHEN value_type='s' THEN str ELSE CAST(num AS varchar(128)) END as val
 FROM mytable
) p
PIVOT 
(
 MAX(val)
 FOR category in ([A], [B], [C])
) pv
ORDER BY ccy DESC
```

The above works in [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16), but the syntax might be slightly different in your DBMS. You can [see it working here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/sx2MDUGI) The biggest drawback is that you do need to list the possible values in `category` that you want converted to columns, so for more complicated problems you might end up using dynamic SQL.

Although a pivot is the correct way of doing this, I want to include a different version that also solves your problem:

```
WITH cte AS
 (SELECT ccy, category, CASE WHEN value_type='s' THEN str ELSE CAST(num AS varchar(128)) END as val
 FROM mytable)
SELECT
  ccy, 
  (SELECT MAX(val) FROM cte c2 WHERE c1.ccy = c2.ccy AND c2.category = 'A') A,
  (SELECT MAX(val) FROM cte c2 WHERE c1.ccy = c2.ccy AND c2.category = 'B') B,
  (SELECT MAX(val) FROM cte c2 WHERE c1.ccy = c2.ccy AND c2.category = 'C') C
FROM cte c1
GROUP BY ccy
ORDER BY ccy DESC
```

I'm including this since I think it is very easy to read and understand how you can create columns like this. If you are doing a quick one-off analysis and aren't used to `pivot`, I think things like this can be very useful. (But, I'm recommending the `pivot` example.)